# Pre-defined stylesheets in Neo4j browser

Tags: browser, neo4j, jqassistant

My project called jQAssistant (https://jqassistant.org) comes with a maven goal which starts an embedded Neo4j server using

```
    this.server = new WrappingNeoServer(databaseAPI);
    this.server.start();
```

which then can be used with a web browser to explore data scanned from Java classes.

As of Neo4j 2.0.0-M06 there is the new Neo4j Browser which can by styled using GraSS(?) files. I'd like to deliver the jQAssistant Maven plugin with some pre-defined styles - is there a way of doing this (e.g. by adding a resource somewhere in the class path)?